# Is there a possibility to pass custom parameters to jenkins while tagging?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I try to create automatic tagging for jenkins on successful build. There are inbuilt parameters for creating tags. Like JOB_NAME , BUILD_ID etc,

Is it possible to pass a custom value in the param? My requirement is, everytime the build is tagged, it should be tagged as Build-1, Build-2 etc. is there any way to do this?

Comment: how do you tack the incrementor? and why would you want to do that? if build-2 refers to build #5 in jenkins because build 2-4 have failed, would that not confuse your users? I'd use BUILD_NUMBER variable to be consistent between tags and builds.

Comment: Do you want to create an SCM tag?  If so, what are you using for SCM?

Comment: @Poppy did you get any useful help? How did you resolve it? I am facing the same issue here.